# Android Studio layer-list render

Tags: android

After wrote `layer-list` I got some error, refresh it but not working.
This is the image of error I got when after place this `layer-list`.

[image]

Comment: Your xml file in layout folder ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be your `xml` file is in `layout` folder.

Move your `xml` file to `drawable` folder. And check it.

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution worked. but why won't place `drawbale` folder? isn't it a layout?